# Update stack bar chart d3 v3

Tags: d3.js

I try to update a stack bar chart with new data. I can make it update with v4 but just out of curiosity wanted to make also a v3 of it. The data is read in correctly, it just doesn't redraw. I tried several different options as in [here](http://bl.ocks.org/alansmithy/e984477a741bc56db5a5), [here](http://jsfiddle.net/duvpM/20/) and [here](https://bl.ocks.org/jfsiii/963694ae9799d99f24a0e01646c68783). 
Would much appreciate if someone can come up with a solution. Thanks

```
   var causes = ["eu", "nonEu"];

   var margin = {top: 20, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 20},
       width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
       height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

   var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
       .rangeRoundBands([0, width]);

   var y = d3.scale.linear()
       .rangeRound([height, 0]);

   var z = d3.scale.category10();

   var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
       .scale(x)
       .orient("bottom");
       // .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%b"));

   var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
       .scale(y)
       .orient("right");

   var svg = d3.select("#stacked").append("svg")
       .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
       .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
     .append("g")
       .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

   d3.csv("data.csv", type, function(error, data) {
     if (error) throw error

     console.log(data)

     var select = d3.select("#menu")

     select.selectAll("option")
          .data(data)
          .enter()
          .append("option")
          .attr("value", function(d) {
            // console.log(d)
              return d.group;
          })
          .attr("id", function(d) {
              return d.group;
          })
          .text(function(d) {
              return d.group;
          });

      select
        .on("change", function(d) {
            value = d3.select(this).property("value");
            console.log(value);
            var graphic_data = data.filter(function(d) {
              return d.group == value;
            })
            console.log(graphic_data)
            draw(graphic_data);
        });
    function draw(graphic_data) {
      var layers = d3.layout.stack()(causes.map(function(c) {
        return graphic_data.map(function(d) {
          return {x: d.group, y: d[c]};
        });
      }));
      console.log(layers);


      x.domain(layers[0].map(function(d) { return d.x; }));
      y.domain([0, d3.max(layers[layers.length - 1], function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; })]).nice();

      var layer = svg.selectAll(".layer")
          .data(layers);

      layer.enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "layer")
          .style("fill", function(d, i) { return z(i); });

      var newLayer = layer.selectAll("rect")
          .data(function(d) { return d; });

      newLayer.enter().append("rect")
          .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y + d.y0); })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y + d.y0); })
          .attr("width", x.rangeBand() - 1);

      newLayer.exit().remove();

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(xAxis);

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ",0)")
          .call(yAxis);

    }
   });

   function type(d) {
     console.log(d)
     // d.date = parseDate(d.date);
       console.log();
       var eu = +d.eu*100/(+d.eu + +d.nonEu);
       var nonEu = +d.nonEu*100/(+d.eu + +d.nonEu);

       d.eu = eu;
       d.nonEu = nonEu;

     return d;
   }
```

Data

```
group,eu,nonEu
fuel,40,60
cars,446,50
medicine,567,435
```

Comment: It seems x and y scales are not updating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it. Create a draw function that draws the initial bar. After the click the update function is executed. Important part is that in the update function you don't enter and append elements again. Silly me...

```
function update(commodity) {

  var graphic_data = data.filter(function(d) {
    return d.group == commodity;
  })


  var layers = d3.layout.stack()(causes.map(function(c) {
    return graphic_data.map(function(d) {
      return {x: d.group, y: d[c]};
    });
  }));
  console.log(layers);


  x.domain(layers[0].map(function(d) { return d.x; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(layers[layers.length - 1], function(d) {console.log(d); return d.y0 + d.y; })]).nice();

  var layer = svg.selectAll(".layer")
      .data(layers);

  // layer.enter().append("g")
  //     .attr("class", "layer")
  //     .style("fill", function(d, i) { return z(i); });

  var newLayer = layer.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { console.log(d);return d; });

  newLayer.exit().remove();

  newLayer
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { console.log(d.y);return y(d.y + d.y0); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y + d.y0); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand() - 1);

  svg.selectAll(".axis.axis--x")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.selectAll(".axis.axis--y")
      .call(yAxis);


}
```